# c/c++ va_list about hook

Tags: c, hook, variadic-functions

```
    void foo(int fmt, ...)
    {
    }

    //I hook foo

    static void (*original_foo)(int fmt, ...);
    void replaced_foo(int fmt, ...)
    {
      printf("Hooking");
      va_list args;
      va_start(args, fmt);
      //do something
      va_end(args);
```

//But I want to call the original_foo function, 
//I do not know how to invoke it ...

```
    }
    //Hook Function not include ...

    Hook(foo, replaced_foo, (void **)&original_foo);
```

Comment: You can't with standard C - you'll have to drop to assembly or something platform specific.  If there's a variant of `foo()` that takes a `va_list` argument (like `vprintf()` is such a variant for `printf()`) then you can pass `args` to it.

Comment: That's pretty much the answer rather than a comment :-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a corresponding `original_foo_v()` which takes a `va_args`, you are lucky: you can use that.

If you don't (such as if you use `DbgPrintf()` or `LStrPrintf()` for interfacing with LabVIEW), you'll have to craft something on your own.

Essentially, you'll have to

- examine the `va_list` you get,
- find its stack frame by walking along the stack,
- allocate as much memory on the stack as you need, assuming that you need the whole area between where the `va_list` points to and the next stack frame,
- calling the non-`va`-aware function.

Of course, you'll have to do this for each and every platform you intend to support...

Good luck and have fun.

Comment: for example int ioctl(int fildes, unsigned long request, ...);

Comment: `ioctl(2)` is a different thing - [The third argument is an untyped pointer to memory.  It's traditionally char *argp (from the days before void * was valid C), and will be so named for this discussion.](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/ioctl.2.html)